# Update an entry with AutoMapper, entry get by LINQ

Tags: c#, nhibernate, automapper

When I execute the code below, in address on `Mapper.Map` line it's ok I have the right values coming from the model but the `customer.Address`, an `ISet` collection, is not updated on `session.Save(customer)` line. Should be updated since `address` is a reference.

```
public ActionResult SaveAddressInvoice(CustomerAddressForView model)
{
    var tx = session.BeginTransaction();

    var customer = session.Get<Customer>(customerId);
    var address = customer.Address.Where(x => x.Id == myAddressId).First<CustomerAddress>();

    address = Mapper.Map<CustomerAddressForView, CustomerAddress>(model);

    session.Save(customer);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

If I do:

```
var address = customer.Address.Where(x => x.Id == myAddressId).First<CustomerAddress>();
address.Street = "MyStreet";
```

I see the entry changed in the collection.

The configuration mapping is:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerAddressForView, CustomerAddress>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Any idea?

**Update 1**

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<CustomerAddress> Address { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        Address = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<CustomerAddress>(); 
    }
}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this: `var address = customer.Address.Single(x => x.Id == myAddressId);` ?

Comment: You might need to include the relevant parts of `CustomerAddressForView` and `CustomerAddress` classes.

Comment: @gdoron nothing, I get the right value from the Collection. When I update the value received with Automapper, the collection is not updated. When I update a field of the value get from the collection, the collection is updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why NHibernate isn't updating the `CustomerAddress` object referenced by `customer.Addresses` is because the `address` variable **gets overwritten with a new object** in the call to the `Mapper.Map` method:

```
address = Mapper.Map<CustomerAddressForView, CustomerAddress>(model);
```

AutoMapper creates a *new* `CustomerAddress` object, which isn't associated to the retrieved `Customer`, hence nothing gets updated when you call `session.Save()`.

You need to **pass a reference** to the retrieved `CustomerAddress` object to AutoMapper in order to update its properties:

```
var address = customer.Address
    .Where(x => x.Id == myAddressId)
    .First<CustomerAddress>();
Mapper.Map(model, address); // Updates the existing address
```